# Would it be reasonable to air-drop suicide pills during the Rwandan Genocide?

Tags: philosophy-of-war

1. Thus I ask a different question - barring legal requirements, is my question a reasonable one?
2. By the bye, has any philosophers published on the ethics of suicide in a war?

---

## Original Question on History SE

Words can't describe the [rape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rape_during_the_Rwandan_genocide#Rape_as_a_weapon_of_genocide), pain and suffering in the Rwandan Genocide:

> Major Brent Beardsley, assistant to Dallaire, gave testimony at the ICTR. When asked about the sexual violence he had witnessed, he stated that the killing blows tended to be aimed at the reproductive organs, and that the victims had been deliberately slashed on the breasts and vagina. Beardsley also testified to having seen the bodies of girls as young as six and seven who had been raped so brutally that their vaginas were split and swollen from what had obviously been gang rapes. He concluded by saying "Massacres kill the body. Rape kills the soul. And there was a lot of rape. It seemed that everywhere we went, from the period of 19th of April until the time we left, there was rape everywhere near these killing sites."[<sup>[13]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rape_during_the_Rwandan_genocide#cite_note-FOOTNOTENowrojee2007364-14)

Alison Woods. Sep 23 2009. [Toronto Star](https://www.thestar.com/news/canada/2009/09/23/haunted_by_a_genocide_canada_ignored.html):

> Up to a million dead, women with babies hacking other women with babies to death with machetes, blood flowing through the streets – a five-page memo from celebrated former diplomat Robert Fowler painted a startling picture of genocide following a trip to Rwanda in mid-May 1994.

It was obvious that the genocide wouldn't be stopped (see beneath). Thus why didn't foreign nations furnish some help in the form of suicide pills, that could've been air-dropped in child-resistant bottles? [It's obvious that some people would rather die painlessly than be violated](https://theconversation.com/could-there-be-a-link-between-genocide-and-suicide-80071):

> Armenian women killed themselves rather than surrender to Turkish rape.
>
> Konrad Kwiet [wrote that](https://academic.oup.com/leobaeck/article-abstract/29/1/135/937237/The-Ultimate-Refuge-Suicide-in-the-Jewish?redirectedFrom=PDF) suicide was the “ultimate refuge” for German Jews during the Holocaust. Some 10,000 of 550,000 German Jews killed themselves between 1925 and 1945 – a huge number at an inordinate rate.

---

**Background**

I quote [Maj (Ret) Brent Beardsley](https://www.ushmm.org/confront-genocide/speakers-and-events/all-speakers-and-events/rwanda-conference/voices/major-brent-Beardsley), who substantiates [the developed world's unhelpfulness in the Rwandan Genocide](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/shows/ghosts/interviews/beardsley.html):

> Luckily, the French did land. They did secure the airport, and they announced that they were coming just strictly to get out their expatriates. What that meant was anybody that was white-skinned got to get on an airplane and fly to safety, and anybody that was black-skinned got to stay in Rwanda and get killed. That's as simple as it came down to. It still to this day leaves a very, very bad taste in my mouth that the United States of America could have 350 Marines sitting at [Bujumbura, Burundi] airport, that the French were able to get in 500 or so paratroopers, that the Belgians had over 1,000 paratroopers.
>
> You know, we basically had our intervention force already on the ground. What they later told us, it was impossible to get on the ground. We had it on the ground on April 10, within three days of this thing starting. But it wasn't there to intervene. It wasn't there to save Rwanda; it was there to save white people, and that's what it came down to. White people were saved and black people were not. For those of us who lived through that time, it still leaves a pretty bad taste in our mouths.
>
> […]
>
> There's this myth that has come out of Rwanda that it was impossible to intervene and stop this genocide. The facts go in the face of it. Within three days, there was 2,000 troops on the ground, and that could have been the start of a bigger operation and bring in even more. They had a decisive impact from the moment they hit the ground. If they'd only have stayed, I still believe that we could have prevented what happened, and I'll take that to my grave.

Comment: IMO, it is very difficult to address these sort of ethical dilemmas... If we forget "practical" issues, why air-drop suicide pills to "help" the good ones, instead of air-dropping bombs to kill the bad ones ?

Comment: A genocide is not "reasonable" in any sense of the word. Thus, we may start agreeing that any attempt to stop a genocide will be reasonable. Thus, my comment above must be read from this point of view: why can be more ethical to help the killer to exterminate the victims than help the victims to survive ?

Answer (score 5):

> Is my question a reasonable one?

The question is misconceived as the commenters you quote have already pointed out, and hence any connection to utilitarianism is tendentious.

A better question would be what could the world have reasonably done once the Rwandan genocide was under way and/or beforehand.

The world had already debated that question in the aftermath of the holocaust and the UN General Assembly adopted the Convention on the Prevention and Punishment of the Crime of Genocide in 1948 and which came into force in 1951.

The most reasonable action to have taken then was to declare that a genocide was underway and to use the political instruments at hand to prevent and punish such a crime against humanity.

This was **not** done. In fact, Major General Romeo Dallaire was sent to Rwanda with a small peace-keeping force in 1993 to oversee the Arusha Accords, a peace treaty between the Tutsis and the Hutus after the Rwandan Civil War, but his room for action was tightly constricted by Chapter 6 of the UN Charter. He said:

> ”We were there as facilitators and not soldiers. The use of force was purely for self-protection.”

On January 11th 1994 he was told by a commander that militias were preparing for mass atrocities. And on the same day he sent a fax to the UN Security Council based in New York to say that he was prepared to act though any action would strictly fall outside the mandate of Chapter 6. Dallaire said:

> [The militias] would be able to kill a thousand Tutsis in twenty minutes, as they were planning ... [We wanted] to go after the weapons cache and  throw off the extremists from doing that ... We got the fastest response that I ever got from New York. They said, ‘you will not respond. You will not put troops at risk.’

For two months he kept asking for authorisation for limited military action to prevent violence and just as they got some agreement the genocide began. Three weeks later 2000 peace-keepers has been withdrawn and the UN Security Council was still discussing whether Dallaire had a mandate to act.

In 1998, Clinton, who was the US President when the killings began in Rwanda told genocide survivors in Kigali

> We did not act quickly enough after the killings began.

Which, though true, misses the substance of the criticism. That is they were well-informed about the situation. Dallaire commented:

> Most of it is crap ... A month before the genocide began, [Clinton] produced a presidential directive that states that the US would not engage in any humanitarian actions unless it is in its self-interest ... He had instructed his staff -  I have had the opportunity to meet some of his subordinate staff - not to tell him what the hell was going on.

In fact, the National Security Archive, a Washington based NGO, went to court to obtain intelligence briefings under the Freedom of Information Act. It discovered that the CIA National Intelligence daily, which went to both Clinton’s desk as well as to the then vice-Presidents, Al Gore plus *hundreds* of other senior officials included almost daily reports on Rwanda. One dated the 24th April 1994 said rebels would continue fighting

> to stop the *genocide* ... which was spreading south.

Three days later, the State Departments Intelligence briefing to Warren Christopher, the then Secretary of State and to other officials noted

> partition and genocide

And reported declarations of a

> *final solution* to eliminate all Tutsis.

What all this shows is that there was a catastrophic lack of leadership by the UN Security Council and by the then US Government, a government that likes to style itself as ‘the leader of the free world’.

Lt. General Dallaire after taking early retirement has devoted himself to the question of taking effective action at a global level by instigating the project, The Will to Intervene at the Montreal Institute of Human Rights & Genocide that aims to operationalise The Responsibility to Protect at the national government level. This is a global political commitment, endorsed by all members of the UN in 2005, to address war crimes, genocide, crimes against humanity and ethnic cleansing.

All this would be endorsed by utilitarianism as a careful reading of John Stuart Mills essays on the subject shows. In fact, Mills was driven to a more sophisticated interpretation of Bentham Utilitarianism after Macauley’s savage critique of his doctrine as a tendentious kind of logic that dumbs down politics and ethics to mere whim.